# Protected member access works only when not getting its address

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have multiple inheritance (class `A` is base class, `B` derived from `A`, `C` derived from `B`).
`A` has a protected member attribute, which I try to access in different ways in `C`.

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
protected:
        int x;
public:
        A() : x(42) {}
};

class B : public A {
};

class C : public B {
protected:
        typedef B Precursor;

public:
        void foo() {
                cout << Precursor::x << endl;
                cout << this->x << endl;
        }

        int get() {
                return Precursor::x;
        }

        int* getPtr() {
                // error: ‘int A::x’ is protected
                // error: within this context
                // error: cannot convert ‘int A::*’ to ‘int*’ in return
                return &Precursor::x;
                //return &this->x;  // this works
        }
};


int main() {
        C obj;
        obj.foo();
        cout << obj.get() << endl;
        cout << obj.getPtr() << endl;
}
```

In `C::foo()` and in `C::get()`, `Precursor::x` works to access `x`.
However, `&Precursor::x` does not work. Why is that? `this->x` and `&this->x` always works.

Clang error message:

```
cpp-inheritance.cpp:34:22: error: 'x' is a protected member of 'A'
                return &Precursor::x;
                                   ^
cpp-inheritance.cpp:7:6: note: must name member using the type of the current context 'C'
        int x;
            ^
cpp-inheritance.cpp:34:10: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int *' with an
      rvalue of type 'int A::*'
                return &Precursor::x;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Can't reproduce first error (accessing `x` in `C`) on ideone: are you sure this is the code that failed?

Comment: `cout << x << endl;` should work here. I have a feeling that your original code had templates in it which made `x` by itself not work.

Comment: The last one produces a pointer-to-member. You need to specify the instance explicitly: `&this->Precursor::x`.

Comment: @interjay: Oh yes, I had. I was simplifying the code later on and didn't realized that this case worked then.

Comment: `&(Precursor::x)` should work as well. Looks like it's yet another ambuguity in the C++ syntax.

Comment: Isn't this multilevel inheritance instead of multiple.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Why is that? Is this a special rule, specific for pointer-to-member? Why does `&(Precursor::x)` work then? And if this is the answer, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Albert It's too late to edit out the "need to". See interjay's answer.

Comment: Did you try `int* getPtr() { return &x; }` ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `&` operator is used on a qualified name of the form `C::m`, where `C` is a class and `m` is a non-static member, it returns a pointer-to-member of type `C::*T` where `T` is `m`'s type. This is a special case that overrides the default behavior of returning a pointer to the expression used as `&`'s operand.

To get a pointer to `C::m` where C is a base class, you will have to make it so that the operand of `&` is not a qualified name, for example with `&this->C::m` or `&(C::m)`.

Reference: C++14, 5.3.1/3

> If the operand is a qualiﬁed-id naming a non-static member m of some class C with type T, the result has type “pointer to member of class C of type T” and is a prvalue designating C::m

Answer (score 0):

Because Precursor::x is not static member of class, you cannot get its address. You need to declare instance, and get address member of instance. This is why this->x works: 
1. C inherits B it has member x inherited from B 
and 
2. this designates current instance of C.

Comment: This explains why `cout << Precursor::x << endl;` works... *how*? Did the last error message, a type conflict between `int*` and `int A::*` escape your analysis ? I think you're on the right track, but just need clearer wording in why `int*` and `int A::*` aren't synonymous.

Comment: This has nothing to do with static members. After all, accessing `Precursor::x` does work despite `x` not being static - it means "the x member variable inherited from `Precursor`" in this case.